# Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS) Exception Codes: ç at 0x3ec3b04c Crashed Thread: 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

HI got the this crash report on device log and I am using the ad hoc build.

I didn't find where it was crashed "0   ???  0x3ec3b04c 0 + 1053012044"

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x3ec3b04c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
<b>0 ??? 0x3ec3b04c 0 + 1053012044 </b>
<b>1 libgcc_s.1.dylib 0x303d29c0 _Unwind_SjLj_Unregister + 24 </b>
<b>2 ??? 0x00000018 0 + 24</b>
</pre>
```

Comment: Is that the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, your application tried to access released variable. While debugging you can use **NSZombie** to detect such variable before receiving `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.